# Using Regexp in Ruby Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to retrieve all objects that satisfy this query:

```
Admin::MyTable.where("Name REGEXP ?", "^#{MyName}-[\d]{1,10}")
```

Ex:

- MyName-1
- MyName-10
- MyName-1000

And so on...

PS: I tried with RLIKE also,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RLIKE` and `REGEXP` are synonyms.

Change `[\d]` to `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`; MySQL does not handle `\d`.